# Book about Human-eating Alien Lizards

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I am looking for a book that I read in the early 2000's in middle school.

The main character was a teen girl. I don't remember how she got to where she was but she ends up finding out that everyone around her are lizard-type, alien creatures who disguise themselves as her friends and family. They are only being nice to her in order to fatten her up enough to eat.

It reminds me of Coraline in some ways.